# Number of valid sequences!

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

A sequence consists of 1,-1,2,-2,3,-3. The sequence is considered valid if

1. It's empty
2. If **S** is a valid sequence the so is "1 **S**-1","2**S**-2","3**S**-3"
3. If S1 and S2 are valid, then so is the sequence formed by their concatenation.

Now a sequence **S** is obtained in which some numbers are missing and are represented by '**?**'
If the '**?**' can be replaced by any of the above numbers.

Find total number of valid sequences that can be formed.

For example-
1 ? 1 2 ? -1 -2 ? -3 ?

Answer is 3 and the valid sequences are

1 3 1 2 1 -1 -2 -1 -3 -1

1 -1 3 2 1 -1 -2 3 -3 -3

1 2 1 2 -2 -1 -2 3 -3 -1

Comment: Then what is your question? - Wait a minute, how dows 1 -1 **3** 2 1 -1 -2 3 -3 -3 match the given pattern?

Comment: @Hagen: (1 -1) (3 (2 (1 -1) -2) (3 -3) -3).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen See the parenthesing: 1 -1 3 2 1 -1 -2 3 -3 -3  = (1 -1) (3 (2 (1 -1) -2) (3 -3) -3)

Comment: @hagen My ques is if given such a sequence in how many ways can the '?' be replaced to form a valid sequence.

Comment: For *this given* sequence you gave the answer yourself. For any other sequence answer is not known, so nobody will give it. Possibly you meant to ask 'how can the number of valid replacements be determined efficiently?', which is a question about an algorithm, not about a number of a replacements.